# A big Problem with Cloud IAP - I need support

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-vm

problem with IAP

I used the option to open SSH terminal on the Cloud console  to connect to VMs.
3  days before I created a new VM, configured it, tested the webserver and everything
it was working normally  UNTIL I decided stopped and started the VM. I dont know how, but something happened, I stopped having access to the webserver and then I went to connect with the VM. Then  Cloud SSH now require Cloud IAP (but I didn't enable it). I tried using the connection option without Cloud IP( an option showed) and it doesn't work either. I followed the steps to create access via proxy. I inserted the allow-ingress-from-iap firewall rule, but I couldn't create the TCP tunnel. I connect through my laptop from multiple locations.

I tryed to  deactivate Cloud IAP. GCP  report it as deactivated but VMs still working as Cloud IAP is active.

How do I get back to using(connect with) my VMs whithout Cloud IAP?

An interesting aspect: one of the VMs has ssh access via an external app. usind it the connection report this

-bash-4.1$ Last login: Tue Apr 18 03:16:24 2023 from 201.17.114.71
-bash-4.1$ Last login: Tue Apr 18 09:11:39 2023 from 35.235.241.65
-bash-4.1$ Last login: Tue Apr 18 09:15:10 2023 from 201.17.113.239
-bash-4.1$

and  gpc console ssh  works.... normally

this means this VM is going through the proxy. But it's been in production for 4 years and hasn't even been "touched".

can anyone help me at this point? I've been awake for over 24 hours, stressed and I can't find a solution.

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: As a first step, add an SSH key to the VM. Then connect using an SSH client. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys